# A problem about homomorphism on polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

**Problem** Let $F[x,y,z], F[t]$ be the polynomial ring of 3 unknowns and 1 unknown respectively on a field $F$. Define a ring homomorphism $\phi$:
\begin{align*}
\phi :F\left[ x,y,z \right] &\rightarrow F\left[ t \right] ,
\\
f\left( x,y,z \right) &\mapsto f\left( t^2,t^3,t^4 \right) .
\end{align*}

Prove that $\ker(\phi)$ is an ideal generated by $y^2-x^3$ and $z-x^2$.

---

**My thought**

Denote ideal generated by $y^2-x^3$ and $z-x^2$ by $\left<y^2-x^3,z-x^2\right>:=\{p(y^2-x^3)+q(z-x^2)\mid p,q\in F[x,y,z]\}$. I try to prove that $$\ker(\phi)\supseteq\left<y^2-x^3,z-x^2\right>\cdots\cdots(\#1)$$ and
$$\ker(\phi)\subseteq\left<y^2-x^3,z-x^2\right>\cdots\cdots(\#2).$$

For  $(\#1)$, when $x=t^2,y=t^3,z=t^4$, we have $y^2-x^3=z-x^2=0$. It is immediate that

$$\ker(\phi)\supseteq\left<y^2-x^3,z-x^2\right>.$$

However, I have no idea how to prove $(\#2)$ despite racking my brains. If it is all about single-variable polynomials, division with remainder may work(dividing $p \in \ker(\phi)$ by $y^2-x^3$, $z-x^2$ and showing the remainder$=0$), but I don't know how to do it in a multi-variable situation.

Any help or discussion would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What sort of machinery do you know/are you wanting to use? Is this part of an algebraic geometry course, or is this purely commutative algebra?

Comment: @Matt This problem is an exercise from abstract algebra course for sophomores. The course is carried out from group theory, then ring and field, finally Galois theory, and this problem is from ring theory. I expect to use some sort of division with remainder on multi-variable polynomials.

Comment: Hints: (i) Try to show that any $f\in F[x,y,z]$ can be written $f=g+(z-x^2)h$ where $h\in F[x,y,z]$ and $g\in F[x,y]$. (ii) Try to show that any $g\in F[x,y]$ can be written $g=p+y q+ (y^2-x^3)r$ where $p,q\in F[x]$ and $r\in F[x,y]$. (iii) With this decomposition of $f$ show that $f$ is in $\ker\phi$ implies $p=q=0$.